Different and conflicting licenses in one repository
Let me ask you directly using an example: there is a repository LINK that has a top-level LICENSE file with the Apache license.
However, in the source files there is this note:

This Page can only be used by business who purchase this product and can be modified as needed.
Mention the Author and Website in your code This will encourage me to create mer project like this

There is this note in one of the JS files:

This Page can only be used by business who purchase this product and can be modified as needed.


Mention the Author and Website in your code This will encourage me to create mer project like this


This Application is license under Evanto Market Terms and Conditions.


This Product is Exclusive on Evanto

The GitHub profile description clearly states

"All applications in this account are developed by  and copyrighted by <website_url>".

Even though I'm experienced in helping others with licensing, I'm having trouble with this. Can I assume that this project is under the Apache 2 license?

Have you tried to reach out to the author? It is unclear what "this page" and "this product" refers to. Evanto Market Terms and Conditions are definitively incompatible to OSS.

I've contacted author and I'm waiting for an answer.

Looking at the repository in question, I see no mention of the Apache License other than its inclusion as a file. The README indicates no intent to license any part of the project under this (or any) license, and several of the files positively indicate a refusal to license the work to anyone except paying businesses.
Considering that GitHub allows you to automatically add a license file at repository-creation time (and the commit history indicates this feature was used here), it seems likely that the author here erroneously selected Apache 2 in the GitHub interface, and then uploaded a codebase whose notices are obviously not related to the Apache license.
It is exactly to avoid this kind of confusion that the FSF (and the Apache 2 text itself) recommends including per-file header notices that affirmatively indicate the licensing of each piece of code, rather than relying on filesystem proximity to a standard license document. In fact, the author here has done exactly that strategy, but in this case, the licensing terms they diligently indicate within each file are obviously no nonfree.

That's how I read it: the person who uploaded it to GitHub didn't really understand what they were doing, and didn't intend to license it under Apache2.  Hopefully, they'll clarify, and fix their GitHub site accordingly.  In the meantime, however, even though I think you're right that they didn't intend to license under Apache2, I think a strong argument could be made that they have done so.

@MadHatter In the APACHE license there is a definition for "Work", though. And it says that the Work must be "as indicated by a copyright notice that is included in or attached to the work". Since that wasn't done here (i.e. none of the source files seem to indicate that they are Apache-licensed), then I think that assuming that it's Apache licensed just because you included the LICENSE.Apache file in the same directory, would be a mistake.

@Brandin because the licence isn't binding on the rightsholder, you can't use the rightsholder's failure to abide by a provision of the licence as an argument that their licence grant is invalid.  The argument that it's been licensed is that the rightsholder deliberately performed an action which has the effect of so licensing the code; their argument against would presumably be that they did not understand that effect and did not intend it.  Courts have gone both ways on whether such things remain in effect; I can't say you'd win such an argument, but I do say you can make it quite strongly.

I support this answer. No-one can really assume that a file is licensed under Apache 2.0 where the header of the file clearly and unambiguously states something completely different. The Apache license declaration for the entire GitHub Project might possibly apply for files in that project which have no other license declaration at all, but in order to be on the safe side you would have to ask the author for clarification. Anything else is walking on thin ice.

Yes, you can assume that the project is under Apache-2.0.
When it comes to conflicting licenses, a general rule of thumb is that the other conflicting license cannot revoke any rights granted by the other conflicting license. The other license can however expand the rights.
In the case of contractCreator the expanding one is Apache-2.0 so you can also use it under Apache-2.0 terms.

I do not think your answer is correct. Your 'general rule of thumb' does not exist. Each file in a project has its own license. If the licenses are conflicting, then the project might be impossible to use. Imagine a project with Apache license, which has a dependency with GPL license. The consensus here is that the entire Project would need to be under GPL.

You are right that you can't license a GPL dependent project with Apache license. I was too quick to assume that in the question's case the project is multi-licensed which means a 3rd party can choose either license to comply with. In a conflicting dual-licensed project one should ask the owner just like you commented on the original question. Should I delete my answer to avoid confusion?

Given the downvotes it's accreting, I might be tempted to delete it if it were my post.  Your call, though.

The Apache license clearly says that to apply the Apache license to your work, you must attach the "boilerplate notice" to your work, but in this case it was not done, so I don't see how anyone could assume this is Apache licensed, unless they are just blindfully trusting the GitHub license detection result (that's possible, but again it's a mistake).

See my comments on your comment supra.  You can't infer anything from someone's failure to do something that they have no obligation to do.  The same analysis applies to eg people who license their works under GPL but fail to include a copy of the licence, violating eg GPLv3 s4; there are lots of those, and nobody has (to my knowledge) seriously claimed that the licence grant is invalid solely because of the absence of the licence file.
